# Cache GZIPed content with nginx

Tags: nginx

I am wondering if nginx can keep in cache the gziped content or it gzip the file all the time?

*By "keep in cache", I mean something in memory or disk, on server side (no browser cache).*

Because I see huge difference between static compression (with `sendfile` on), and using nginx gzip module (cant work with `sendfile`).

Comment: Do you have to use nginx for cache? you can try nuster, https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, able to cache gziped content

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know Nginx does not keep gzipped content in memory - managing a cache like that would likely make it slower and more complex in most cases and not help 99% of use cases, because the overhead of gzip is usually low.

I would recommend using [`gzip_static`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html#gzip_static) instead - if you enable it, Nginx looks for the requested file with an additional .gz ending and serves this instead of gzipping itself, so if someone requests bigfile.png and Nginx sees there is bigfile.png.gz too, it will serve the .gz file as gzip and do no calculation itself. I use this for all resources which can be prepared in advance (JS, CSS, images, XML). Because you only gzip once, you can also use the highest compression ratio.

Comment: I think so too, but wondering why so many Nginx configuration examples never mention that. Especially those that mix ``sendfile`` and ``gzip`` .

Comment: I think they don't mention it because Nginx is usually very explicit with what it is doing - it does not try to guess, and it tries to do everything fast, so it never does anything additional behind the scenes. That often makes it easy to understand, because you do not get caught unawares by surprising behavior.

Newer versions of Nginx have a lot of explicit caching features, but caching is always hard (what to cache, how long, how to find out if something changed) and has overhead. And it is hard to make Nginx slow anyway: Even "unoptimized" most things run very well.

Comment: If you enable ``sendfile`` and ``gzip`` , sendfile will not work. This is not explicit.